# Is it correct that staying in postdoc position for more than 3 years is a negative thing?

Tags: postdocs, career-path

I am working as a postdoc at a reputable university. The salary and funds are quite good, no less than an assistant professor at our university. However, some of my friends are saying that staying in a postdoc position for more than 3 years is a negative thing. Especially since I currently have an offer for a non tenure track assistant professor position from an average-rank university.

Is it correct that staying in a postdoc position for more than 3 years is a negative thing?

Comment: It might be dependent on the specific system. As well on the post doc age, and his/her feeling concerning an advancement at the current institution, as well as a multitude of factors linked to private life.

Comment: It depends on the person evalutaing. Some will see this as negative, most will probably look at your scientific achievements and ability to aquire funding during this time.

Comment: This will also depend on the field. For example, Biomed researchers seem to stay as post-docs longer than, say, engineering researchers.

Comment: What's your career goal?

Answer (score 2):

This is a question which depends highly on specific circumstances, and thus cannot be answered universally in a reliable way.
Some important parameters:

- country (East Europe? Russia? USA? UK? China? India? Iraq?)
- field of study: norms in your field of study? How competitive is your area? (Is it history or machine learning?)
- More specific parameters: do you have better alternatives?
- Etc.

That said, it is generally (read: on average, considered across all possible parameters distributed with uniform probability) correct, in my opinion, that staying too long as a postdoc is negatively correlated with getting a permanent academic position. This is because empirically "aged" academics are perceived negatively sometimes by recruitment committees.